# Dynamically generate data-driven Mocha tests using the data obtained before method

Tags: node.js, typescript, async-await, mocha.js

I'm attempting to dynamically generate test cases based on the data retrieved from an API.

Below is the Mocha test class:

```js
describe('Test suite A', function() {
    var serviceClient: ServiceClient;

    var serviceProviderCode: string;

    let negativeTests: any[];

    before(async function() {

        // Retrieve data from dependency services first.
        const networkServiceClient = await ClientFactory.createNetworkServiceClient();

        serviceProviderCode = (await networkServiceClient.getActiveServiceProviderList())[0].companyCode;

        serviceClient = await ClientFactory.createServiceClient();

        negativeTests = CreateMovementData.negative(serviceProviderCode);
    });
    
    negativeTests
        .forEach(({testCase, payload, expectedStatusCode, expectedError}) => {
            it(testCase, async function() {
                const response = await serviceClient.createMovement(payload);
                
                response.status.should.equal(expectedStatusCode);
                expect(response.data.error).to.deep.equal([expectedError]);
            });
        });
});
```

Below is the class which is responsible for generating the data:

```js
export class CreateMovementData {

    public static negative(serviceProviderCode: string){
        return [
            {
                testCase: "Should not be able to create with service provider only",
                payload: { serviceProvider: serviceProviderCode },
                expectedStatusCode: 400,
                expectedError: {err: "bad request"}
            },
            {
                testCase: "Should not be able to create with invalid delivery service code",
                payload: { serviceProvider: serviceProviderCode, deliveryServiceCode: 'invalid delivery service code'},
                expectedStatusCode: 400,
                expectedError: {err: "bad request"}
            }
        ]
    }
```

**Problem**:  The `negativeTests` remains undefined and it is not generating the tests as expected.

Further debugging shows that the `negativeTests.forEach(...)` being invoked before the `before()` function completes.

How can I ensure the execution is in the following order?

1. `before()` function completes, hence the `negativeTests` variable had initialized.
2. `negativeTests.forEach` invoked to generate the test cases

Any advise / suggestions would be greatly appreciated.